# What happens when an APK is installed on SD card?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, installation

Say we want to install an APK named **x.apk** to an Android phone.

By default, at least two things will happen:

```
1. Copy x.apk to /data/app;

2. Create a package folder under /data/data as the private storage space;
```

However, if **x.apk** is to be installed on SD card,

What are the folders corresponding to **/data/app** and **/data/data** on SD card?

Comment: In addition when an app is installed a folder is created under /data/app-lib/ containing libraries extracted from apk and dalvik cache is created under /data/dalvik-cache. When you install or move an app to sdcard an encrypted filesystem image is created containing apk and something else I can't check right now. That image then is mounted under /mnt/(asec?) sorry i can't check right now because my phone doesn't support moving apps this way.

Comment: I can confim /mnt/asec and encrypted image file is under sdcard/.android_secure/